# How to combine member of a column, collect them in a data frame and give them a new name, in R?

Tags: r, group-by, merge, count

I want to make a new data frame based on my old data frame and combine members of a specific column while I give them a new name:
for example, this is my old data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(ID= c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x2", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3", "x3"),
col1=c("a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2","a2"),
col2= c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"),
col3= c(2,13,1,21,0,5,3,0,6,4,50,0,0,0,0,9,5,0,51,3,6,0,0,9,89,4,29,1,4,17,6,16,9,1,0,0)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-36L))
```

and for the new dataframe I want to have a new column based on **col2**, so combine **abc**, where there is any of **a** or **b** or **c**, name it as **abc.1**. Combine  **de** where there is **d** or **e**, name it as **de.5** and finally where it is **f** name it as **f.10**. and for the **new.col3** the SUM of their **value** in old **col3**.

The result would be:

```
df2<- structure(list(col1=c("a1","a1","a1","a2","a2","a2"),
new.col2= c("abc.1", "de.5", "f.10", "abc.1", "de.5", "f.10"),
new.col3=c(25,89,5,213,6,26)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create groups with `case_when` and then use `summarise` to collapse rows by groups and compute the sum of `col3` by group.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(col1, gp = case_when(col2 %in% c("a", "b", "c") ~ 1,
                        col2 %in% c("d", "e") ~ 5,
                        col2 == "f" ~ 10)) %>% 
  summarise(new.col2 = paste(paste0(unique(col2), collapse = ""), unique(gp), sep = "."),
            new.col3 = sum(col3))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   col1 [2]
  col1     gp new.col2 new.col3
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
1 a1        1 abc.1          25
2 a1        5 de.5           89
3 a1       10 f.10            5
4 a2        1 abc.1         213
5 a2        5 de.5            6
6 a2       10 f.10           26
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`,

```
df[,new.col2:=fcase(col2 %chin% c('a','b','c'),'abc.1',
            col2 %chin% c('d','e'),'de.5',
            col2 == 'f','f.10')][,.(new.col3=sum(col3)),by=.(col1,new.col2)]
```

**Output**

```
   col1 new.col2 new.col3
1:   a1    abc.1       25
2:   a1     de.5       89
3:   a1     f.10        5
4:   a2    abc.1      213
5:   a2     de.5        6
6:   a2     f.10       26
```